# Model field missing in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

The invoice_date field on one of my models is not showing up in my admin.

```
invoice_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

I've tried the following:

- renaming the field
- running makemigrations/migrations
- restarting the server
- deleting cookies

I can successfully write to the field and pull data from it, so it appears to be there and functioning as desired. I just can't see it in the admin.

I have no special code in my admin.py. I've just registered the model

**admin.py**

```
from userorders.models import UserCartItem
admin.site.register(UserCart)
```

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoring to [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add):

> As currently implemented, setting `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` to `True` will cause the field to have `editable=False` and `blank=True` set.

You can circumvent this by explicitly [defining it on the `ModelAdmin` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields):

```
from userorders.models import UserCartItem

class UserCartItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['invoice_date']
    fields = ['invoice_date']
    # if you want the field just to visible but not editable
    # readonly_fields = ['invoice_date']


admin.site.register(UserCartItem, UserCartItemAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something following-

```
from userorders.models import UserCartItem

class UserCartItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ['field_name_1', 'field_name_2', 'invoice_date']

admin.site.register(UserCartItem, UserCartItemAdmin)
```